# OpenMP: how to handle race condition on global std vectors

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, openmp

I'm interested in parallelize a for loop using OpenMP where global std vectors are involved.

In this specific example, the order in which the operation `vec[1] = vec[1] + i` is executed doesn't matter however the results appears to be wrong sometimes due to race conditions. What is the proper way to handle this?

The REDUCTION clause seems not working for containers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

std::vector<double> vec = {1,1};

void func(int i){
    vec[1] = vec[1] + i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int k;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(k=1; k<10; k++){
        func(k);
    }
    std::cout << vec[0] << ", " << vec[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the line

```
vec[1] = vec[1] + i;
```

isn't atomic. When compiled, it looks more like this

```
auto tmp = vec[1];
tmp = tmp + i;
vec[1] = tmp
```

And in this case, you have a race condition.

If you want to do it that way, you can tell OpenMP that your `vec[1] = vec[1] + i;` should be atomic, like so :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> vec = {1,1};

void func(int i){
    #pragma omp atomic
    vec[1] = vec[1] + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int k;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(k=1; k<100; k++){
        func(k);
    }
    std::cout << vec[0] << ", " << vec[1] << std::endl;
}
```